SequelizeConnectionError: role "node" does not exist

I have integrated sequlize into my NextJS project. Also, write the migration script for the schemas to be created into PostgreSQL. But, at the time of POST api call I am receiving the error saying: "Error inserting data ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: role "node" does not exist"


Code in .sequlizerc
module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('src/config', 'database.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('src/db', 'models'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/db', 'migrations')
}```

The config file (database.js)
```sql
module.exports = {
    development: {
        username: PG.USERNAME,
        password: PG.PASSWORD,
        database: PG.DB,
        host: 'postgres',
        port: 5432,
        dialect: 'postgres',
        schema: 'public',
        seederStorage: 'sequelize',
    }
};

Model configuration in index.js file. ('src/db/model/index.js')
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';
import { basename as _basename, join } from 'path';
const basename = _basename(__filename);
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://username:password@host:5432/dbname', {
  schema: 'public',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: false,
  },
  logging: true,
  seederStorage: 'sequelize'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Sequelize authenticated & connected successfully!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js'
    );
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, 
      Sequelize);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default db;

Users Model at /src/db/models/Users.js path
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Users = sequelize.define(
      'Users',
      {
        userid: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      {},
    );
    Users.associate = function () {};
    return Users;
};

Now, in the POST api when it triggers it throws above error.
const models = require('../../db/models').default;
const result = await models.Users.create({
  userid: '111_ABC',
});

Versions in package.json file
"next": "13.1.6",
"next-auth": "^4.23.2",
"pg": "^8.12.0",
"sequelize": "^6.37.3",
"sequelize-cli": "^6.6.2"


first of all, I need you to do console.log(PG) variable to make sure that the values is exist. Secondly, I need you to console.log(file) inside your foreach

Looks like you haven't created the user in Postgres so it can't authenticate.
